# How to create an installer/setup project for my visual basic WinForms application with a LocalDB and SQL connection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, localdb

I am currently trying to create a setup project for my WinForms application and, after using the setup created, cant seem to get my app fully functional. I made an installer for my application using both (primary output) and the physical files (database, database.log, winformsapp.exe, winformsapp.exe.config files) to define the projects dependencies/prerequisites within the application. Both setups run into the same error after installing the program (when I run my installed application, it runs my applications splash/loading screen, then runs idle in the background unseen where it should prompt for a serial key-- more specifically, if working correctly, a dialog box pops up after the loading bar is done, you click it then the serial key screen pops up--). When I run the original "winformsapp.exe" -- held within "project-name/bin/debug/" --  it runs perfectly; it connects to my database strings no problem, runs through the loading screen, prompts to a serial key/ takes me straight to application if the serial key is already entered.

This is what i'm looking at visually...

**"SQL SERVER A" CONNECTION STRING (database for product serial keys):**

```
const string connectionString = @"Server = XXXSERVERNAMEXXXSQLEXP; DATABASE = berrysdatabase; USER ID = larryman99; PASSWORD = manlarry99;";
```

**"LOCALDB A" CONNECTION STRING  (database used by user, datagridview based)**

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Win_10\source\repos\Localiteration\Localiteration\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security = True");
```

ORIGINAL EXE FILE RUNNING from '/projectname/bin/debug' (USED TO CREATE SETUP)

https://gyazo.com/61e3fc1fdcb56db2a171057786f8e8f3

works perfectly... after clicking the dialog box, you are prompted to enter a serial key, you rerun the program and the exe authenticates and runs perfectly ( this form appears):
pops up after clicking the "goto activation form" you pop up briefly above

[image: pops up after clicking the "goto activation form" you pop up briefly above]

I attempt to use this perfect exe file in a setup for my visual basic program:

[image: Files i used for the installer]

**My setup prerequisites: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2**

**I included SQL 2019 Local DB in my prerequisites and it made no difference**

When I run the exe within the setup folder after it is created, this exe does not work the same... the splash screen appears, loads, then my program disappears and runs in the background where it should be prompting me for a serial key or, if the serial key is entered, let me fully into the program. I am very confused because the original exe works fine:

https://gyazo.com/36835e38e3e726f02757b51e151d142c

I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here, any help would be very appreciated...

I created a setup/installer with/without SQL Server 2019 Express LocalDB and it runs the same either way after being installed through the created setup

Comment: Please do not post links to files for the users here to download. If the information is important, then include it in the content of your question, preferably as DDL and DML statements. USers are very unlikely to download your files, especially when you are a new user and therefore (without offence) the users here have no reason to trust the legitimacy of the files from a complete stranger.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by download... I uploaded all my images/gyazo straight to the website, no special links here... maybe im confused...

Comment: I assumed that the links were not images, as they weren't inserted as images, @Bussarin, and I wasn't going to click a link to a website I do not know.

Comment: @Bussarin don't post links to images on other sites. Add the images to the question itself, making sure they are visible *without* forcing people to click on anything

Comment: `my program disappears and runs in the background` that sounds like an exception thrown in the program itself, before the splash screen is shown. Add exception handling there and log the exception at least. Check Event Viewer too - when an application crashes an event is logged including the full exception text. If your application is still running though, you must have added code that prevents it from crashing in case of unhandled exceptions

Comment: haha understood, thank you for the edit! I will make sure to figure out how to post this way for the future.

Comment: Please don't figure this out in the future, address this in your existing question, @Bussarin .

Comment: I was unsure how to use event viewer, I copied my entire project folder from my main system, attempted to run the "working exe" and it ran the same as the exe supplied through my setups (launched then idle in the background after loading screen). I opened my project in visual studio on my second system I was prompted to install .net foundation and sql data sources, I currently see "Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll" in the output window when debugging